# How do have different styling on an input that is clicked or tabbed into using Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

For design reasons, when a user tabs into an input field the input's border should change color. But if the user clicks into the input field, the rest of the site is also greyed out.

I believe there isn't a way to do this with straight html and css. So I am looking for a way doing it using js. The application uses Angular.

Currently I have it setup to call on click and focus from the html. This works correctly for tabbing. However when a user clicks in, both click and focus are called.

HTML for the input:

```
<input
  name="search"
  type="search"
  autocomplete="off"
  placeholder="Search"
  onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
  onblur="this.placeholder = 'Search'"
  (click)="activateSearchBoxTakeover()"
  (focus)="activateSearchBoxHighlight()"
  [class.tm-homepage-search-header__search-input--click]="isSearchTakeover"
  [class.tm-homepage-search-header__search-input--tab]="isSearchHighlight">
```

Component.ts

```
export class HomepageSearchHeaderComponent {
  public isSearchTakeover: boolean;
  public isSearchHighlight: boolean;

  public activateSearchBoxTakeover (): void {
    console.log('click');
    this.isSearchTakeover = true;
    this.isSearchHighlight = false;
  }

  public activateSearchBoxHighlight (): void {
    console.log('not click');
    this.isSearchTakeover = false;
    this.isSearchHighlight = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fix" I have gone with is having the default :foucs styling doing what I want for tabbing. Then using the click function to add a class that overrides the default styling.
This way I also have minimal js.